# Video embedding in website

Tags: java, asp.net, .net, jsp, video

i have to embed videos into my webpage. I have used `<video>` tag of HTML5. I have `.mp4` and `.flv` files mostly. Firefox doesn't support `.mp4` format. If i have only one file, named `myVideo.mp4` which is not supported in Firefox, should i first change its `format` to many other video formats (.avi, .flv, .swf etc) so that it may be used in all major browsers? Like following

```
<video width="444" height="444" controls>
 <source src="myVideo.mp4">
 <source src="myVideo.flv">
 <source src="myVideo.avi">
</video>
```

Comment: How to convert? I want to convert programatically not manually

Comment: You must have all three file types uploaded to your website; then you can use the code you have

Comment: I am working in asp.net mvc. Is there helping stuff for format conversion in .net?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Your browser (unable to read mp4) has no chance to convert the video on-the-fly into a format it knows. Therefore you need to have the different video formats stored on your server, or as links.

A great tool for video conversion is http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-flv It allows you to resize, modify bitrate, etc.

Also, you should specify the type of your src as such :

```
<source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />  
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

And about flv. You need a fallback to flash if your browser doesn't support the  element of HTML5. If so, adding a .flv won't work, you need to embed a full Flash player. All decent flash player read mp4 videos, so you won't need a .flv at all actually.